# How to merge audio and video in JW Player?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer, jwplayer6

We have some .mp4 videos which has no audio. Now i want to add a audio track to that videos. I have implemented all player functionality in JW Player. Is it possible to play both the .mp4 and .mp3 files at the same time? if yes please guide me how to do.

My current code is like below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player').setup({
        width: '60%',
        height: '60%',
        primary: "flash",
        playlist: [{
            image: "15.png",
            sources: [{ 
              file: "anim_card_flip.mp4"
            }],
            title: "RK Movie Trailer",
            tracks: [{  // i want to specify audio file like this
              file: "ringtone.mp3"
            }]
        }]   
});
```

Comment: You could set up multiple players, but without doing a huge amount of custom scripting, there's no way to synchronize them, and each would have its own controls. Remember, JW Player isn't actually "processing" the video or audio in any way - it's letting the browser play the video/audio, using either the browser's own HTML5, or using Flash. JW can't manipulate the file contents.

Comment: ^ Yeah, you would have to set up two players, and play they both at the same time. The player is just a player, it doesn't do anything with the media fed into it, other than play it back.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Ethan and @MisterNeutron that Player is just a player, Player will only process the video or audio, it won`t merge. it doesn't do anything with the media fed into it, other than play it back.

I think You should look for some other solution which helps you to merge the video and audio into one in mp4 format and then play it with jwplayer

while searching for solution I found about [recordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/merging-wav-and-webm-into-mp4.html) (other [link](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) )and [ffmpeg](https://kwizzu.com/construct.html), using ffmpeg you can merge video, you need to explore more about [this](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg) and how it works.

> Once you have downloaded both video and audio files
>   (‘videoplayback.mp4’ and ‘videoplayback.m4a’ respectively), here’s how
>   you can merge them into a single file:
>
> ```
>  - Download and install ffmpeg. Open a Command Prompt window in your
>    downloads folder and run the following command
>
>  -  ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -i videoplayback.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
>
>  - Wait until ffmpeg finishes merging audio and video into a single file
>    named "output.mp4".
> ```

Some more helpful links

1. [how to merge mp4 and m4a files (ffmpeg method)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXfp4S1xZsw)
2. [how to mix in audio to html5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203604/how-to-mix-in-audio-to-html5-video) ( This solution is same as suggested by @Ethan and @MisterNeutron, to create two instance of player and use one for audio and other for video)

I hope this helps :)